# How to create a dynamic form with flask without WTForms

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

What I am trying to do is create a form that is automatically generated and then the values from that form are then used to proceed in the program. Currently to generate my form I am using this function

`real_names=["Jason","Casandra"]`
this portion of the code is not static it is generated with the names of the previous part of the form.

```
     form = """
            <h2>What fields do you want your employee's on?:</h2>
            <dl>
            """
            def form_creator(name):
                            print name
                            dt = "<dt>"
                            dt_1 = dt+name.title()+":"
                            dt_kill = "</dt>"
                            input_basic_1 = '''<input name="''' 
                            input_basic_2 = """" size="1"> </input>"""
                            generated_input = dt_1+ input_basic_1 + name.lower() + input_basic_2+dt_kill
                            # flash(generated_input)
                            return generated_input
    for i in real_names:
                print ("\n\n"+i+"\n\n")
                form += form_creator(i)
```

`return render_template('assign_score_b.html',form=form)`

The HTML code is

```
{% extends "assign.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
   {{form|safe}}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Now after I generate the form and then get the varibles from the user I would like to process the form but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the values to be checked. What I was trying to do for the answers was

```
answers = []
for i in real_names:
    testable_var = request.form[i]
    try:
        int(testable_var)
    except:
        flash("Please submit an number not a letter")
    answers.append(testable_var)
```

but when I was trying to do this I got a error request. Using WTForms is ***NOT*** an option Your help will be very appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code will work but you made one small crucial mistake.
So your names are `"Jason" and "Casandra"` but the names of your form are `"jason" and "casandra"` The names themselves are capitalized but the form values aren't! Your code will work if you lower the variable `i` you can do this simply with string manipulation all you have to do is add on `.lower()` to your variable therefore your code would look like this:

```
for i in real_names:
    testable_var = request.form[i.lower()]
    try:
        int(testable_var)
    except:
        flash("Please submit an number not a letter")
    answers.append(testable_var)
```

now your code will work!